# out of present range bug javascript IE 7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

hey guys i have following javascript below

```
   for(var k in style){
      if(style.hasOwnProperty(k)){
        this.elem.style[k]=style[k];
     }
    }
```

where style is an object e.g

```
     {'maxHeight':'50px','maxWidth':'50px'}
```

in IE 7 am getting out of present range error because of

```
    this.elem.style[k]=style[k];
```

any other way i can set the style  using object oriented way

thanks

Comment: Can you split the assignment into `var x = style[k]` and `this.elem.style[k] = x` to find out which of the accessors throws that error?

Comment: hey thanks . i was setting zindex to 9999999999 which i guess IE 7 does not support. now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

> I was setting zindex to 9999999999 which i guess IE 7 does not support

The highest z-index IE7 supports is `999999999`, i.e. 9 digits.